# How to create, read and write a sharedPreferences file?

Tags: java, android

I have a voice recording app that record voice and save it into a WAV file.   when naming the file I would like to be able to name it Recording X.wav,  with X being replaced with a number.  I would like to store a counter that counts how many files have been created, so when a recording is finished it adds one onto the counter.  A lot of SO posts suggest using a shared preferences file,  but I can't find it my shared preferences file anywhere in the project directory.  How can I create one, Read it and write to it?

(PS I'm a beginner with Android studio so could you please try and dumb down the answer for me?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create SharedPreferences in you project without finding it in the project directory. This is actually stored in your project folder in the app file system once created (*/data/data/YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME/shared_prefs/YOUR_PREFS_NAME.xml*). 
But for creating, updating and retrieving you do not want to go there.

To Create SharedPreference

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("MyPreference", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
 editor.putString("name", "Nathan");
 editor.putInt("id", 1000);
 editor.apply();
```

To retrieve

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("MyPreference", MODE_PRIVATE); 
String name = prefs.getString("name", "Blank Name"); //"Blank Name" the default value.
int idName = prefs.getInt("id", 0); // 0 is the default value.
```

Please go through the below link for more details.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences?hl=en

Answer (score 3):

```
    public class Pref {

        private  static final String PREF_FILE = BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID.replace(".","_");
        private static SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = null;

        private static void openPref(Context context) {
            sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        }

        //For string value
        public static String getValue(Context context, String key,String defaultValue) {
            Pref.openPref(context);
            String result = Pref.sharedPreferences.getString(key, defaultValue);
            Pref.sharedPreferences = null;
            return result;
        }

        public static void setValue(Context context, String key, String value) {
            Pref.openPref(context);
            Editor prefsPrivateEditor = Pref.sharedPreferences.edit();
            prefsPrivateEditor.putString(key, value);
            prefsPrivateEditor.commit();
            Pref.sharedPreferences = null;
        }

        //You can create method like above for boolean, float, int etc...
    }
```

If you want to store string data than you can write like below:

```
Pref.setValue(mContext,"test", "Test123");
```

If you want to fetch string data than you can write like below

```
Pref.getValue(mContext,"test", "your default value");
```

this one return String value as "Test123". If you getvalue without setvalue than it will return your default value here it is "your default value".