# Unable to save data via SharedPreferences in Android

Tags: java, android, textview, sharedpreferences

I'm unable to save data from `textView` when I'm opening an app again I'm getting error in textview:

> Error message Field XXXXX should be numeric

I think it's not saving any data or I'm using an incorrect method. Thank you in advance!

```
  class MyJavaScriptInterface {
        @JavascriptInterface
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        public void processHTML(final String html) {
            myWebView.post(new Thread() {
                @Override public void run() {
                    TextView text = findViewById(R.id.textView);



                    if(!sharedPreferences.contains("statusKey")){
                        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("prefID", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                        editor.putString("statusKey", html);
                        editor.apply();
                        text.setText(html);
                    }
                    else {
                        text.setText(sharedPreferences.getString("statusKey", ""));
                    }

                }
    });
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you provide the full error stack?

Comment: Why javascript tag is here?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58922686/how-to-create-read-and-write-a-sharedpreferences-file/58927591#58927591, please check this

Comment: I suppose that your editText's inputType isn't a text, try to add to your editText attribute android:inputType="text"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You initiating sharedPreference late after checking condition. So first fix that.

```
class MyJavaScriptInterface {
    @JavascriptInterface
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public void processHTML(final String html) {
        myWebView.post(new Thread() {
            @Override public void run() {
                TextView text = findViewById(R.id.textView);



                sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("prefID", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                if(!sharedPreferences.contains("statusKey")){
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                    editor.putString("statusKey", html);
                    editor.apply();
                    text.setText(html);
                }
                else {
                    text.setText(sharedPreferences.getString("statusKey", ""));
                }

            }
       });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @DHAVAL ASODARIYA working perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

```
class MyJavaScriptInterface {
    @JavascriptInterface
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public void processHTML(final String html) {
        myWebView.post(new Thread() {
            @Override public void run() {
                TextView text = findViewById(R.id.textView);

                sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("prefID", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                if(!sharedPreferences.contains("statusKey")){

                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                    editor.putString("statusKey", html);
                    editor.apply();
                    text.setText(html);
                }
                else {
                    text.setText(sharedPreferences.getString("statusKey", ""));
                }

            }
});
    }
}
```

Try above code